# Redirect the ajax response to another jsp page with response data open in new tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I am submitting form using Ajax, where I am getting the response of another jsp.I want to redirect this another jsp into new tab.

```
$.ajax({ 
    data: $('#frmPrintReports').serialize(), 
    type: $('#frmPrintReports').attr('method'), 
    url: $('#frmPrintReports').attr('action'), 
    success: function(data, status, xhr) { 
        console.log("result : " + data);//here I get the another jsp data which I want to redirect to new tab

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("some error");
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the point of making an AJAX request if you're just going to do a redirect when it completes anyway?

Comment: ajax request submit the form data into backend and after processing on form data backend return the url along with another jsp.I want to display that url on new tab.this another jsp is intermediate page for redirection.